# AutoFill DocuSign Text Fields with c# SDK

Tags: docusignapi

I am using the DocuSign c# SDK and am trying to auto-populate text fields in a DocuSign template with values from an HTML form. I can get the FullName and Email fields to populate as I believe that information is being passed via TemplateRole. However, I can't seem to find an example of how to pass information into a custom field I have created. Everything I can find is pure JSON requests. I assume there has to be methods within the SDK to handle this. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
    public EnvelopeSummary CreateEnvelopeFromTemplate(LoanApplicationModel model)
    {
        EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
        envDef.EmailSubject = "DocuSign Test - Please sign this document";

        TemplateRole tRole = new TemplateRole();
        tRole.Email = model.Email;
        tRole.Name = model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName;
        tRole.RoleName = "Client";

        List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() {tRole};

        envDef.TemplateRoles = rolesList;
        envDef.TemplateId = "*******";

        envDef.Status = "sent";

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envDef);

        Console.WriteLine("EnvelopeSummary:\n{0}", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelopeSummary));
        Trace.WriteLine("Envelope has been sent to " + tRole.Email);
        return envelopeSummary;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside TemplateRole, you need to use Tabs, and if you need to populate for instance TextTab, then you need to add `textTab` like below to your tRole and the `TabLabel` of the `TextTab` should match exactly whats present in your template.

```
tRole.Tabs = new Tabs();
tRole.Tabs.Text = new List<Text>();
Text text = new Text();
text.TabLabel = "<Template_DataLabel>";
text.Value = "<Value_which_you_want_to_prepoulate>";
tRole.Tabs.Text.Add(text);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. The only thing I want to note is that where you have 'tRole.Tabs.Text = new List<Text>()' I had to write 'tRole.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();'. Not a big difference at all, but wanted to put that up for anyone else who may come by this. Thank you.